# Installing Rmpfr in R 3.2.2 on Mac OS X (10.10.5 Yosemite)

Tags: r, macos, homebrew

I installed R on Mac OS using homebrew. Until now everything was smooth. Today, I wanted to use arbitrary precision on some calculations on R. I saw that `Rmpfr` package is easy to use, so I decided to install it. First, I used the usual:

```
install.packages("Rmpfr")
```

and I received this message:

```
checking for mpfr.h... no
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found; maybe use --with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
```

So I discovered that the mpfr headers were in `/usr/local/Cellar/mpfr/3.1.3/include`, but not in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`

I symlink them, and also the libs in `/usr/local/Cellar/mpfr/3.1.3/` to `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`. After that, it starts to compile, but then I received the following message:

```
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -o Rmpfr.so Ops.o Summary.o convert.o init.o utils.o -lmpfr -lgmp -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: library not found for -lmpfr
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Rmpfr.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
```

Any ideas what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

After several hours trying different options, finally I discovered a work around.
I simlink the libs to the R path:

`cd /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1/R.framework/Resources/lib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mpfr/3.1.3/lib/libmpfr.* .
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a/lib/libgmp* .`

After that, I ran:
`install.packages('Rmpfr', type = "source", configure.args=c('--with-mpfr-include=/usr/local/include','--with-mpfr-lib=/usr/local/lib'))`

And everything compiled OK.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Jorge posted a question and then posted a solution. It's fairly common that Mac users encounter difficulties related to directory placement for homebrew installed packages and there are not many canonical places to find this information. Admittedly he should have come clean in the question that he had installed R in a non-standard location, but I imagine this will be of value to other users,

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run `brew link gmp mpfr` to create the missing symlinks.

Comment: Cool!!, I didn't know the `link` functionality in `homebrew`. Thanks!